# Adding Next & Previous Buttons to modal with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button, lightbox, simplemodal

I have made a clean modal to use on a website to open images, everything works fine and is pretty nice.

Now I want to make a next image and previous image button for a better user experience.
I have a plan, so I find the index of the current image that is in the modal and I increment it by one on the next button, and decrement it by one on the previous button, HM ok seems easy enough. So how do I go about doing this?
this is my Modal code

```
window.onload = function() {
  var imgArr = document.getElementsByClassName("myImg");

  var modalWindow = document.getElementById("myModal");
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
  var caption = document.getElementById("caption");
  var span = document.getElementById("close");
  var modalBlock = document.getElementById("modalBlock");

  for (i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
    var picture = imgArr[i];
    var list = Array.from(imgArr);

    picture.onclick = function() {
      openImg(this);
      var index = list.indexOf(this);
      console.log(index);
    };
  }

  function openImg(pic) {
    modalWindow.style.display = "block";
    modalBlock.style.transform = "translateY(0%)";
    modalImg.src = pic.src;
    modalImg.alt = pic.alt;
    caption.innerHTML = modalImg.alt;
    imgIndex = picture[i];

    bodyScrollLock.disableBodyScroll(myModal);
  }






};
```

Now I have the open image that I've clicked on and its index, and I'm stuck on what to do next. I've found the w3 lightbox tutorial, but it's so different from my code I need to swap everything. Does anyone have an idea how I can do this with my own code?

A jsFiddle how it looks at the moment
https://jsfiddle.net/superVoja/eoyda1vh/15/

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on building this from scratch then you will need to start thinking about what you should control with HTML and CSS and leave the rest to do with JavaScript.

I would use Modal window set with Html and hide it with CSS, then when image link and trigger fires I would bring modal to front. Using fadein fadeout, opacity and z-index to make sure that is on the front. Set background to black in order to get the Modal effect.

The faster way is to use library like [Lightbox js](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Then overwrite using CSS and maybe some js if need to in order to adjust to your liking.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have done this already with nice effects and everything, now I just want to use the next and previous buttons, but I can't wrap my head around on how would I do this with my own code.

Comment: well why don't you share a code back here. Upload your code with css to jsfiddle.com and share back the link.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/superVoja/eoyda1vh/15/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is the answer I got myself if anyone reads this give yourself some time, you'll find the answer yourself!

I followed my code and did exactly the thing I was trying to do, I found the index of the image that is clicked, and then I just incremented it by one like this.

```
var next = this.document.getElementById("next");
  var slideIndex = "";

  for (i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
    var picture = imgArr[i];
    var list = Array.from(imgArr);
    picture.onclick = function() {
      var index = list.indexOf(this);

      slideIndex = index;
      openImg(imgArr[index]);
      console.log(index);
    };
  }

  next.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    openImg(imgArr[(slideIndex += 1)]);
  });
```

It may not look pretty, but it's mine and I am proud of it!

And here is [a link](https://jsfiddle.net/superVoja/eoyda1vh/22/) How it looks!